# Angular [class.active]="isActive" - what does "class.active" mean here?

Tags: css, angular, class

In a training video of angular, I saw some codes, like these below:

`<button class="nav nav-primary" [class.active]="isActive">`

and in the component, If we let the variable `isActive=true`,then the button has the  "active" class;if let the variable `isActive=false`,then the button has not the "active" class.

I know that this is a one-way binding, but I want to know what's the grammar mean of "class.active"? (the "class" has a property of"active"? but this is impossible.

Answer (score 7):

That means `.active` state of the current `class(style)` of the element is run When `isActive` is **true**.

According to your code,

**In .html File,**

```
<button class="nav nav-primary" [class.active]="isActive">
```

**In .ts File,**

```
public isActive:boolean = true;
```

## I defined 'isActive' as True (default), you can change as you wish ;)

**In .CSS File,**

```
.nav-primary {
              color : "Black";
}

.nav-primary.active {
             color : "white";
}
```

now you can see the colour is **white** when `isActive` is `True` and the colour is **Black** when `isActive` is `False`

Answer (score 0):

It means that you are setting the `class` with name `active` (`class.active`) to that element, if the `expression`, in this case `isActive` property is `true` or can be parsed to `true`.

Don't think about it as a property `active` of the `class`. It just a construct which will be evaluated by Angular to get the name of the class.

From the [**Documentation**](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax)

> You can bind to a specific class name. Angular adds the class when the
>   template expression evaluates to truthy. It removes the class when the
>   expression is falsy.

Comment: but I really want to know:class.active? what "class.active" meaning?the class has a active property?but it's impossible. the class in css is a reserved key word.

Comment: @pies Edited. See

Comment: How is this grammar (class.active) comes？

Comment: This is built in Angular syntax. I gave you the link where you can read more